# How to solve this linear Diophantine equation?

Tags: diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

$$ 61 x - 40 y = 1 $$

I know how to proceed in the addition equations, but how do you find the HCF of a negative number via Euclidean Algorithm? Please explain all steps in detail.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions, as each solution induces another one.

Comment: I am aware of that,but how do you find the general solution via Euclidean Algorithm?

Comment: $\gcd(61,-40) = \gcd(61,40)\,$ since $\,d\mid -40\iff d\mid 40\ \ $

Comment: You're solving the equation in integers. You can let $z=-y$. Then the equation is $61x+40z=1$.

Comment: What does HCF stand for?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo "Highest common factor". It's written as a version of GCD (greatest common divisor) or HCD (highest common divisor) or GCM (greatest common measure) in [the beginning of the gcd Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor).

Comment: You use the algorithm to find x and y such that 61x +40y = 1 and then note that 61x - 41(-y) = 1.

Answer (score 0):

You solve $61x + 40y = 1$, I got $61(-19) + 40(29) = 1$ Then you play with the signs accordingly. In this case $61(-19) - 40(-29) = 1$.